# Is there a way to create a running sum variable that sums the current Bets for every row?

Tags: sum, time-series, rstudio

This is a part of a simulated dataset about Users behaviour in an online game.

```
    UserID     Age Gender Shots
1 1324364       36   male  109
2 1324364       36   male   65
3 1324364       36   male  656
4 1324364       36   male  586
5 1324369       19   male    5
6 1324369       19   male   28
```

I need to have a running variable that creates a sum of the number of shots for every observation but it needs to restart when a new UserID occurs so something like this:

```
    UserID     Age Gender Shots TotalShots
1      64       36   male  109    109
2      64       36   male   65    174
3      64       36   male  656    830
4      64       36   male  586   1416
5      70       19   male    5      5
6      70       19   male   28     33

For reference, here is my data for you to copy/paste into your R.
UserID <- c(64, 64, 64, 64, 70, 70)
Age <- c(36, 36, 36, 36, 19, 19) 
Gender <- c("male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male",)
Shots <- c(109, 65, 656, 586, 5, 28)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(UserID, Age, Gender, Shots)#turn your verctors into a data.frame we can work with  
df$TotalShots <- unlist( mapply(cumsum, split(x = df$Shots, f = df$UserID)), 
                            use.names = FALSE )
```

Apply the `?cumsum` function to the object (vector) that you get by splitting (`?split`) the `df$Shots` along the `df$UserID` `factor`. Since the result will be a `list` - `?unlist` it so you can assign it back to your data.frame as the resulting `TotalShots` column.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.